# Emails Sent with Nodemailer Are Not Using the Correct 'From' Address

Tags: node.js, express, gmail, nodemailer

I'm using the nodemailer library in my Node.js application to send emails. I'm trying to set the 'from' address dynamically based on the currently logged-in user, but the emails are consistently sent from the email adrress that i have set in the configuration  instead of the expected 'currentUserEmail' address.

the problem is :

- Emails are not being sent from the expected 'from' address.
- I have confirmed that 'currentUserEmail' is correctly logged in my backend code, and it contains the desired email address.

**Configuration:**

- I'm using Gmail as the email service.

- My nodemailer configuration specifies 'forworkonly489@gmail.com' as the 'user'.

- I've ensured that IMAP is enabled in the Gmail settings.

- 'Less secure apps' access is allowed in Gmail's settings.

Please find below my relevant code snippets:
my code :

```
app.post('/api/sendMessage',protect, async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, tel, message, currentUserEmail,    } = req.body;

  console.log('Received currentUserEmail:', currentUserEmail);


  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'forwork@gmail.com',
      pass: 'pass'
    },
  });

  // Compose email message
  const mailOptions = {
    from: currentUserEmail, 
    to: 'ABC@gmail.com' ,
    subject: 'New Message from Your Website',
    text: `You received a new message from ${name} (${email}, ${tel}):\n\n${message}`,
  };


  const newMessage = new sendMessage({
    name,
    email,
    tel,
    message,
  });

  newMessage.save()
    .then((message) => {
      // Send the email
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log('Error sending email:', error);
          res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error sending message' });
        } else {
          console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
          res.json({ message: 'Message sent and stored successfully' });
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error saving message to the database:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error saving message to the database' });
    });
});
```

Why are my emails being sent from '**forwork@gmail.com**' even though I've correctly set 'from' to 'currentUserEmail'?

Answer (score 0):

The `user` in the `auth` object should generally match your `from` option.

The sender email is still `forwork@gmail.com` because that's the email address you're using for authentication (because it's your Gmail account).

Gmail uses the values you provide in the `auth` object to basically verify who's sending the email, so even if you specify a different `from` address, the sender is still `forwork@gmail.com`, because that's the Gmail account you're using.

Comment: okay, so the "from" option is automatically set to the user in the auth  object, thx